# Decompress gzip string with golang

Tags: go, gzip

I have a string which contains a gzip compressed string, therefore there's no file headers, standard `compress/gzip` library throws error `gzip: invalid header`

How can I decompress a gzip compressed string in go?

This is what I'm trying

```
nbody := "eNorTk0uSi0BAAjRAoc="
rdata := strings.NewReader(nbody)
r,err := gzip.NewReader(rdata)
log.Println(r)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
s, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r)
fmt.Println(string(s))
```

Comment: `eNorTk0uSi0BAAjRAoc=` - this is no "gzip string". This is  zlib encoded (zlib is not gzip, also it basically just is a different header in front of the deflate encoded content) and then additionally base64 encode, so you need to first decode it from base64 and then use a zlib decompression and not a gzip decompression.

Comment: Is there someway we can re-title this question so it doesn't appear in google searches?

Comment: Can this question be deleted entirely or something? This isn't gzip

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> ... I have a string which contains a gzip compressed string
>
> ```
> nbody := "eNorTk0uSi0BAAjRAoc="
> ```

This is not a  "gzip compressed string". This looks like some base64 encoded data which need to be decoded first. After decoding it is not gzip either but zlib - which is basically the same as gzip (content compressed with deflate algorithm) but with a different file header. Therefore trying to decode it with gzip will not work.

The following will therefore take your original string, decode it from base64 and decompress it using zlib (not gzip):

```
package main
  
import (
        "bytes"
        "compress/zlib"
        "encoding/base64"
        "fmt"
        "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
        b64z := "eNorTk0uSi0BAAjRAoc="
        z, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(b64z)
        r, _ := zlib.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(z))
        result, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r)
        fmt.Println(string(result))  // results in "secret"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how did you knew to use zlib? the input is actually being compressed by Celery (a python tool) where I indicate I want gzip compression, but actually your solution worked, so I want to understand how you detected it's a zlib compressed string

Comment: @perrohunter: The base 64 was obvious. So I did `echo 'eNorTk0uSi0BAAjRAoc=' | base64 -d > f; file f` which showed `f: zlib compressed data`.

Answer (score 20):

Since this question comes up on google all the time if you have real gzip encoded data in a string and want to decode it here's how you'd do that:

```
import "compress/gzip";
import "bytes";
import "io/ioutil";
...

original := "gzipencodeddata";

reader := bytes.NewReader([]byte(original))
gzreader, e1 := gzip.NewReader(reader);
if(e1 != nil){
    fmt.Println(e1); // Maybe panic here, depends on your error handling.
}

output, e2 := ioutil.ReadAll(gzreader);
if(e2 != nil){
    fmt.Println(e2);
}

result := string(output);
```

Comment: codestyle advice: get rid of semicolons in your code, they're useless and trigger gopher eyes

Answer (score 2):

If you have large inputs, you might want to use streams and a custom chain of decoders instead.

It has the advantage that (except for this example) neither the encoded input nor the decoded output has to reside in RAM.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "compress/zlib"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

const nbody = "eNorTk0uSi0BAAjRAoc="

func main() {

    _, err := io.Copy(os.Stdout, decoder(strings.NewReader(nbody)))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error copying decoded value to stdout: %s",err)
    }
}

// This could use any io.Reader as input, for example
// a request body in http requests
func decoder(r io.Reader) io.Reader {

    // We simply set up a custom chain of Decoders
    d, err := zlib.NewReader(
        base64.NewDecoder(base64.StdEncoding, r))

    // This should only occur if one of the Decoders can not reset
    // its internal buffer. Hence, it validates a panic.
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("Error setting up decoder chain: %s", err))
    }

    // We return an io.Reader which can be used as any other
    return d

}
```

<kbd>[**Run on playground**](https://play.golang.org/p/JhArP7p3OV5)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into that but my input comes from a json blob that is pulled from redis, I can turn it into a stream afterwards, for now I got a solution from Steffen Ullrich which works